# Load Gephi input CSV in Neo4j

Tags: csv, neo4j, gephi

I created a csv files (node and edge fle) compatible for Gephi and imported the graph in Gephi. However, the graph had parallel edges which is not supported by geph. I moved to Neo4j for the purpose. However, I am finding it difficult to import the csv files used for Gephi to import in Neo4j.

I looked through Neo4j documentation to import csv files, however it considers these files in rdms style.

Please help to load edge and node csv files in Neo4j.

Sample Node File:

```
Id;attr1;attr2
2;23;A
1;34;B
```

Sample Edge File:

```
 Source;Target;attr3
 1;2;Plays
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at Cypher's [LOAD CSV functionality](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/#query-load-csv). Using your example files the Cypher statements to load the data into Neo4j would be something like this:

First, [create a uniqueness constraint](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/#_using_unique_constraints_with_merge) on the label/property that identifies the unique id (I'll just use `Person` label here, but change to whatever fits your domain):

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (p:Person) ASSERT p.personID IS UNIQUE;
```

Then iterate through `nodes.csv` file to create a node for each row in the csv file:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///nodes.csv" AS row FIELDTERMINATOR ';'
MERGE (n:Person {personID: row.Id})
SET n.attr1 = row.attr1,
    n.attr2 = row.attr2;
```

Note that with Neo4j 3.0+ by default the file url is relative to the `import` directory within `$NEO4j_HOME`.

Then to create the relationships:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///rels.csv" AS row FIELDTERMINATOR ';'
MATCH (source:Person) WHERE source.Id = row.Source
MATCH (target:Person) WHERE target.Id = row.Target
MERGE (source)-[r:KNOWS]->(target)
SET r.attr3 = row.attr3;
```

See [this example in the docs](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/#cypherdoc-importing-csv-files-with-cypher) for more info/options.